# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013: Server Explorer 'Add New Table' and 'New Query' menu items missing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-express

What's wrong with this picture?  In older VS versions, I used to see 'Add New Table' and 'New Query' when I right-clicked *Tables*

Hopefully, someone where has some experience with Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Express databases.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate - Server Explorer - Tables - Add New Table Missing]

Comment: I don't get it.  I didn't get any errors.  Nor can I find any Internet resources that mention this kind of an issue.  I'm really hoping there's a fix for this.

Comment: I'm running a repair on the Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 installation.  Hopefully, that will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. A repair is in process. I did some custom installations of various versions of SQL server on my system sometime after installing VS2013 Express 2013 for web. Maybe that screwed up the framework somehow.

Answer (score 2):

i also hate this problem. But it has an easy solution:
Run your Visual Studio 2013 installer > select MODIFY > check **SQL Server Data Tools** option. If you don't have an installer, you can visit [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/data/tools.aspx) to download **SQL Server Data Tools**.

Answer (score 1):

Running a repair via Windows 'Programs and Features' resolved this issue.  I Had a feeling the problem would be fixed when the repair needed the system to reboot for the repairs to complete.

Comment: Running the repair work for me as well. But it did take over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you only see Refresh and Properties when you right click on Tables in Server Explorer, you probably need to install SQL Server Data Tools from 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027